# CSS: Force float:left for elements within div

Tags: css, css-float

Not sure if I'm just not seeing the wood for the tree's but I'm trying to force a bunch of DIV's to float left - within a constrained block.

My wrapper is 600px x 600px and within that I have a bunch of DIV's (all, also 600x600) and I'm using jQuery to scroll to each one.  Problem is, they sit underneath each other rather than to floating in a row.

Essentially, I want to scroll horizontally, not vertically.  I'm sure I've solved this before, and maybe I'm having one of those days but I just can't get it today :(

Any pointers appreciated.

```
<style>
#parent {width:600px; height:600px;}
.kids {width:600px; height:600px; float:left;}
</style>

...

<div id="parent">
    <div class="kids"> ... some content ... </div>
    <div class="kids"> ... some content ... </div>
    <div class="kids"> ... some content ... </div>
</div>

...

<nav>
   <a>{onclick srolls #parent to left:600px}</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Give the wrapper a larger width, ideally number of child divs * 600 and have a container around the wrapper with a width of 600 and overflow scroll.

Comment: Update your post with HTML and CSS on jsfiddel

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to force the kids to float within the parent regardless of its width.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @TimCutting: Sure, but the parent has to be wide enough for all childrens. Otherwise they will go below. You can calculate the required width with javascript.

Comment: The required width would be exactly 2400px, but I don't want window scroll bars.  Thought I could use display:table and display:table-cell?!  I'll try it out now.  Didn't want to use `<table>` to force it.

Comment: This is all because I want to scroll horizontally, vertically is no problem. display:table idea didn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`

```
<style>
#parent {width:600px; height:600px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;}
.kids {display: inline-block; width:600px; height:600px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Excellent!  I had to ensure that `.kids` had `white-space:normal` set, otherwise the content goes off in to the ether.  Thank you very much!